# SSRS Report display in IE

Tags: reporting-services, report

We have ssrs report version 9.0.0.0 deployed on stage server and it is having some trouble displaying in IE, yet works fine in Chrome.
Please check the attached screen shot.
When I click on view report button , only the report viewer header is displayed in disabled mode and report content is not shown up.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

#### Report Issue

[image: Report Issue]

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying the reports on the `Intranet`, try changing the `Compatibility view` settings.

From IE menu bar, go to `-> Tools -> Compatibility View Settings` check the `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` option.

Comment: Can we do any adjustment in SSRS report or in code.Compatibility View Settings seems to be temporary solution.